# Jquery post not working when adding database conneciton

Tags: jquery, database, post, connection

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnMgpmamLVA

I've uploaded video in youtube that shows my problem exactly as well.
I run the app either way with and without database connection.
No problem without db connection but the problem persists me when i add db connection.
Can someone please suggest and guide me to the right direction?
I'll be so grateful....

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to you post, so I write there.

You have to check connection:

```
$connection = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass')
or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
```

It will show you errors if exist.
Or put echo "some text" between each line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I tried this and it also failed to resolve my problem.
It's been really exasperating me for two days...

Comment: No errors?
Maybe put echo between 3 ($con1) and 4 line ($con) and check result.

Comment: Still no progression.
I think jquery post doesn't even land into index.php file
Anything else did i miss but this is connection i've been using for other jquery posts. There is no problem with post when i add app and add records and delete and so on.
It persists only in deleting eventHandler of wix...